# How can I translate my .vimrc into evil-mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil, vim-emulation, mapping

I have heard of the power of Emacs, but I have a ton more experience with vim and an extensive amount of shortcuts in my `.vimrc` file. I would like to transfer these mappings over to Emacs `evil-mode`. What would be the best way to do this? One example would be mapping <kbd>tab</kbd> to <kbd>>></kbd> (indenting the current line). Which looks like `nnoremap <tab> >>` in my .vimrc.

Comment: In general, this translation is not going to be trivial. Things are done very differently in Emacs, but I think you'll find that Emacs is much cleaner and more powerful in the long-run, although it's a good deal more verbose.

Comment: I think it might be better for you to ask questions about specific corresponding lines from your `.vimrc`, rather than a catch-all question.

Comment: so one cannot just "run the `.vimrc` script I had when text editor in Evil opens up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken literally, your sample line would translate to the following:

```el
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<tab>") (kbd ">>"))
```

Although I don't personally recommend this. It's much cleaner to reference the function you want to run by name instead of using a keyboard macro. This clears up the need for a distinction between `nmap` and `nnoremap`, and is more fault-tolerant.

```el
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<tab>") #'evil-shift-right-line)
```

Comment: How did you know the command was evil-shift-right-line? Experience or is there a library?

Comment: In general, you can use `C-h k` to determine what command a key runs. **However** `evil` does hide some things behind proxy-commands (e.g. `evil-shift-right`) to make the composable grammar easier. In this case, you just have to know that an `evil` operation that works on a whole line is usually `<op>-line`. Examples include `evil-delete-line`, `evil-yank-line`. Some operations, like `evil-downcase` do not define such convenient aliases, so you need more magic to get them to work. Ask if you need help for those.

Comment: so one cannot just "run the `.vimrc` script I had when text editor in Evil opens up?

Comment: @Pinocchio that is correct.

Comment: Why cant i run it?